# c# class design for fields with inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a C# class that I want to reuse for different scenarios. Depending on the scenario, the values of some of the fields will need to change. I was thinking of building an abstract base class and then inheriting. The constructors of the descendent classes would have new field values in them. Something like this:

```
public abstract Class MyBaseClass
{
   protected string var1;
   protected string var2;
   protected string var3;
   public MyBaseClass()
   {
      var1 = string.empty;
      var2 = string.empty;
      var3 = string.empty;
   }
   public bool myfunc()
   {
       //code to do something with var1...var3
   }
}
  public class myderivedclass: MyBaseClass
 {
    public myderivedclass()
    {
     //constructor for derived class
     base.var1 = "whatever";
     base.var2 = "something";
     base.var3 = "somethingelse";
    }
 }

 public class myotherderivedclass: MyBaseClass
 {
    public myotherderivedclass()
    {
     //constructor for derived class
     base.var1 = "new";
     base.var2 = "newer";
     base.var3 = "newest";
    }
 }
```

I would then instantiate myderivedclass or myotherderivedclass and call functions like myfunc to do the work.
Is there a better way to handle these changes in fields or is this a good approach?

Thank-you.

Comment: Make them virtual properties instead, and override them in derived classes

Comment: Could you show me a simple example? Most of the functionality is in the base class btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the difference is only in the initial values this is not a good approach. It's better to introduce a new constructor in the base class that accepts parameters. Then in the child classes just pass different values.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    private string var1;
    private string var2;
    private string var3;

    public MyBaseClass(string var1, string var2, string var3)
    {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;
    }

    public bool Myfunc()
    {
        //code to do something with var1...var3
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
        : base("var1value", "var2value", "var3value")
    {
        //constructor for derived class
    }
}

public class OtherDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public OtherDerivedClass()
        : base("new", "newer", "newest")
    {
        //constructor for derived class
    }
}
```

Moreover, protected fields are not very good practice. If you need to access this members in child classes it's better to introduce protected properties.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    protected string Var1 { get; private set; }
    protected string Var2 { get; private set; }
    protected string Var3 { get; private set; }

    public MyBaseClass(string var1, string var2, string var3)
    {
        this.Var1 = var1;
        this.Var2 = var2;
        this.Var3 = var3;
    }

    public bool Myfunc()
    {
        //code to do something with var1...var3
    }
}

[ ... ] 

public class DerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
        : base("var1value", "var2value", "var3value")
    {
        // constructor for derived class
        // can acces protected members here
    }
}

[ ... ]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if protected fields are actually considered a bad practice, but in my opinion it's a code smell. Fields are usually an implementation detail, and derived classes shouldn't rely on implementation details of their base class.

A cleaner approach would be to change `var1`, `var2` and `var3` to virtual properties, and override them in derived classes.

```
public abstract Class MyBaseClass
{
   protected virtual string var1 { get { return ""; } }
   protected virtual string var2 { get { return ""; } }
   protected virtual string var3 { get { return ""; } }

   public bool myfunc()
   {
       //code to do something with var1...var3
   }
}

 public class myderivedclass: MyBaseClass
 {
     protected override string var1 { get { return "whatever"; } }
     protected override string var2 { get { return "something"; } }
     protected override string var3 { get { return "somethingelse"; } }
 }
```

Comment: example please? I am new to this.

Comment: @AndrewGaskell, I edited my answer to add an example

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish your goal this is using an `interface`. It acts like an `abstract` class, but with only method signatures. Whatever is in the `interface` must be in the inherited class.

For instance:

```
public interface IMyBaseClass
{
     // Properties for classes
     string MyVar1 {get;set;}
     string MyVar2 {get;set;}
     string MyVar3 {get;set;}

     // Method to be implemented
     bool MyFunc();
}
```

And your inherited class would look like this:

```
public class MyInheritedClass :IMyBaseClass
{
    public string MyVar1 {get;set;}
    public string MyVar2 {get;set;}
    public string MyVar3 {get;set;}

    public MyInheritedClass() 
    {
         this.MyVar1 = "whatever";
         this.MyVar2 = "something";
         this.MyVar3 = "something else";
    }

    public bool MyFunc()
    {
       // do some code here
    }
}
```

Notice I didn't have to write `override` on the properties, because if your class is inheriting from an Interface, then you can implement your own implementation per class. Just like an `abstract` class, an `interface` cannot be used as an object.